# redis memory efficiency

Tags: database, memory, redis

I want to load data with 4 columns and 80 millon rows in MySQL on Redis, so that I can reduce fetching delay.

However, when I try to load all the data, it becomes 5 times larger.

The original data was 3gb (when exported to csv format), but when I load them on Redis, it takes 15GB... it's too large for our system.

I also tried different datatypes -

1) 'table_name:row_number:column_name' -> string 
2) 'table_name:row_number' -> hash

but all of them takes too much.

am I missing something?

added)

my data have 4 col - (user id(pk), count, created time, and a date)

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the data you are trying to model, and the access patterns?

Comment: Well you compare flat data to in-memory indexed data ... of course it is much larger. Use hash to represent your rows, minimize key length, and add indexes only on the stuff you really need to index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most memory efficient way is storing values as a json array, and splitting your keys such that you can store them using a ziplist encoded hash.

1. Encode your data using say json array, so you have key=value pairs like `user:1234567 -> [21,'25-05-2012','14-06-2010']`.
2. Split your keys into two parts, such that the second part has about 100 possibilities. For example, `user:12345` and `67`
3. Store this combined key in a hash like this `hset user:12345 67 <json>`
4. To retrieve user details for user id 9876523, simply do `hget user:98765 23` and parse the json array
5. Make sure to adjust the settings [hash-max-ziplist-entries and hash-max-ziplist-value](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization)

[Instagram wrote a great blog post explaining this technique](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs), so I will skip explaining why this is memory efficient.

Instead, I can tell you the disadvantages of this technique.

1. You cannot access or update a single attribute on a user; you have to rewrite the entire record.
2. You'd have to fetch the entire json object always even if you only care about some fields.
3. Finally, you have to write this logic on splitting keys, which is added maintenance.

As always, this is a trade-off. Identify your access patterns and see if such a structure makes sense. If not, you'd have to buy more memory.

Comment: Wow, this is more than I expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

+1 idea that may free some memory in this case - key zipping based on crumbs dictionary and base62 encoding for storing integers,

it shrinks user:12345 60 to 'u:3d7' 'Y', which take two times less memory for storing key.

And with custom compression of data, not to array but to a loooong int (it's possible to convert [21,'25-05-2012','14-06-2010'] to such int: 212505201214062010, two last part has fixed length then it's obvious how to pack/repack such value )

So whole bunch of keys/values size is now 1.75 times less.

If your codebase is ruby-based I may suggest me-redis gem which is seamlessly implement all ideas from Sripathi answer + given ones.